# SQLAlchemy - How to access column names from ResultProxy and write to CSV headers

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use SQLAlchemy to establish a connection to a PostgreSQL Database, execute a SQL query and print the output of the file to a file in linux.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import yaml
import csv

outfile = open('/path/filename.csv', 'wb')
outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')


with open('config.yml') as f:
    cfg = yaml.safe_load(f)
    username = cfg['credentials']['username']
    password = cfg['credentials']['password']
    host = cfg['credentials']['host'] 
    port = cfg['credentials']['port']
    dbname = cfg['credentials']['dbname']
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(username, password, host, port, dbname))
    result = engine.execute("""select * from db.tablename """)

    # dump column titles (optional)
    outcsv.writerow(x[0] for x in result.description)

    # dump rows
    outcsv.writerows(result.fetchall())
    outfile.close()
```

However, I am getting the following error message - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 12, in 
**AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'description'**

If I comment the below command, I am successfully able to get the query result but without the headers.
outcsv.writerow(x[0] for x in result.description)

Upon researching, I found the method - result._metadata.keys can generate the headers. However, it generates in some form of a list that I can't attach as header.

Please advise if there is any way to get the file header as well as the data into a csv file. Please consider the fact that I am beginner in Python while answering the above.

Comment: You can convert keys to a list using `list(result._metadata.keys)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this row in your example:

```
result = engine.execute("""select * from db.tablename """)
```

the variable `result` is pointed to an instance of the class [`sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy).

You want to get the column names to write to the first row of your csv file, and through inspecting your `result` object found `result._metadata.keys` which returns a regular python `list` of column names.

A convention in Python is that whenever an attribute, variable or method on an object is prefaced with an underscore (e.g. `_metadata`) that means it's not intended to be a public API, and the maintainers of the package may change their implementation in such a manner that breaks your code if you rely on these things (however unlikely for a stable library such as SQLAlchemy). Fortunately, in this case there is a documented public API for you to get what you need: [`ResultProxy.keys()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.keys).

Remember that your `result` variable points to a `ResultProxy` instance, so you can access the `keys()` method on that to get the column names, e.g:

```
result.keys()
```

What happens when we try to write to your csv file:

```
outcsv.writerow(result.keys())
```

We get this exception:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm going to assume that this is what you refer to when you say:

> However, it generates in some form of a list that I can't attach as
>   header.

You can have a look at the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) API but the issue is that you've opened the file in such a manner that it expects binary data, not the strings that are returned from `result.keys()`. So if we change the line where you open your file to:

```
outfile = open('/path/filename.csv', 'w')
```

`outfile.writerow` will accept the result of `result.keys()`.

Everything else should "just work".

Here is the code I used to test:

```
import csv

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'model'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    col1 = Column(String(10))
    col2 = Column(String(10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create some test data
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    s = Session()
    data = dict(col1='a', col2='b')
    s.add_all(Model(**data) for _ in range(5))
    s.commit()
    s.close()
    # put the session away and work with the engine

    result = engine.execute("select * from model")

    outfile = open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='')
    outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    outcsv.writerow(result.keys())
    outcsv.writerows(result.fetchall())
```

here's the contents of the csv:

```
id  col1    col2
1   a   b
2   a   b
3   a   b
4   a   b
5   a   b
```

Comment: It worked at my end too. The explanation was very detailed and immensely helpful.